# Laravel nested transaction not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, transactions, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and wants to implement nested transaction.

[Middleware]
- applied for all logics, commits on normal end and rollbacks when exception caused

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    \DB::beginTransaction();
    try {
        $response = $next($request);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        \DB::rollBack();
        throw $e;
    }
    if ($response instanceof Response && $response->getStatusCode() > 399) {
        \DB::rollBack();
    } else {
        \DB::commit();
    }
    return $response;
}
```

[Logic] - nested transaction

```
\DB::beginTransaction();
$modelA->save();
\DB::commit();
$modelB->save()
causeException();
```

What I expected is bellow.

1. modelA inserted
2. modelA commited
3. modelB inserted
4. modelB rollbacked

But what's happeing is below.

1. modelA inserted
2. modelB inserted
3. modelA and modelB rollbacked

It looks like nested "\DB::commit();" in logic is not working.
How can I handle nested transaction on Laravel?

If it's not possible, then what is the best practice for this case?
Most of the time, I want to commit on normal end and rollback when exception caused (without writing codes for each logic), but very occasionally want to manually commit or rollback for specific logic.

Comment: Do you need to explicity use `beginTransaction()` method?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. If I explicitly use beginTransaction(), I thought I could exclude changes before beginTransaction() from the nested transaction.

Comment: If a transaction fails then everything that is done within the transaction is rolled back, including other transactions. That's intentional

Comment: I would strongly advise against whatever it is you're doing. If there are things that should not be written in the database if there is an error then you should wrap those sections and those sections alone in a transaction. Transactions are meant to solve the critical section problem in databases. If your entire code is a critical section you need to review your code.

Comment: You mean I should not wrap entire logic by transaction using middleware? I do so because I don't want to make inconsistent data when an exception happens.

Comment: I think you're right that only section which requires transaction should be transactional. I optimized the code for 99% of all logics, that is "commit on normal end, rollback on exception" logic, and that is causing trouble for the other 1% of logic that needs to be transactional partially. I'd like to know how to handle this 1% without losing convinience for other 99%.

Answer (score 0):

Well, specific for your use case, you may use the following hack, but I myself is not recommending it:

1) In your middleware you have something like this:

```
DB::beginTransaction();
... {
    DB::commit();
} ... {
    DB::rollBack();
}
```

2) Since you want something to behave like a checkpoint for your code, you can write something like this to behave as a checkpoint:

```
...
DB::commit();
DB::beginTransaction();
...
```

So that whenever a checkpoint is encountered, the original transaction will be committed and a new transaction will start immediately after it. Hope it achieves what you want...